# ndk And-operation between GLuint and a GLuint-type macro

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, macros, operations

i encountered a problem when i try to do a and-operation between a GLuint variable and a macro which type is GLuint.

Description:
   The environment is jni programming on android platform
   I make sure i include the header paths the project needs.

in the .h file, i defined :

```
#define EGL_WINDOW_RGB      0;
```

in the .cpp file, i try to:

```
(flags & EGL_WINDOW_RGB)
```

where flags is GLuint which actually is a unsigned int type.

problem:
    (flags & EGL_WINDOW_RGB) get a syntax error. however, (flags & 0) is ok

Then, i want to know what's the problem

Comment: Remove the semicolon from the end of the `#define` line.

Comment: yes, you're right, i make a stupid.  Thanks